# Ubuntu 11.10 server - Becomes unresponsive until the mouse is moved

Tags: linux-server

I have a server in my house with a mouse and keyboard attached, and a monitor - I installed a GUI hoping it would fix this, it didn't. I can't connect to the server, it just times out. Any IRC connection or anything Times out too, that is until I move the mouse. This Iappens every so often (around 5 hours) and it is annoying because it happens when I am asleep. Does anyone know what is happening? My ZNC users are getting quite annoyed. I may just note that I run a IRC Server - and the topic is kept if it is still running, although I can't connect and it times out when doing this, it still keeps all settings as if it was not a crash. I am just so CONFUSED.

Comment: This issue is getting very annoying, any suggestion at all? ping?

Answer (score 1):

Do you ask in power management that your PC go in hibernate or sleeping mode after a time ? If it is the case, just change the configuration to 'never'. You can put your screen in sleep mode separately.

Comment: The Power management options are that the screen never turns off, as I turn it off manually. There is also no suspend/hibernation options set. That's what is so confusing about it.

Comment: If you check your logs, do you see a log at the suspend time ?

Comment: Which logs shall I check?

Comment: /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages?

Comment: There seems to be no logs of anything happening